# Angular Full calendar View

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar

I'm using an angular full calendar in my project and I have tried this https://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-calendar/#/kitchen-sink.
but in this, I'm getting some errors.

here is my HTML code

```
 <div class="row text-center">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                              <div class="btn-group">
                                <div
                                  class="btn btn-primary"
                                  mwlCalendarPreviousView
                                  [view]="view"
                                  [(viewDate)]="viewDate"
                                  (viewDateChange)="closeOpenMonthViewDay()"
                                >
                                  Previous
                                </div>
                                <div
                                  class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
                                  mwlCalendarToday
                                  [(viewDate)]="viewDate"
                                >
                                  Today
                                </div>
                                <div
                                  class="btn btn-primary"
                                  mwlCalendarNextView
                                  [view]="view"
                                  [(viewDate)]="viewDate"
                                  (viewDateChange)="closeOpenMonthViewDay()"
                                >
                                  Next
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                              <h3>{{ viewDate | calendarDate:(view + 'ViewTitle'):'en' }}</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                              <div class="btn-group">
                                <div
                                  class="btn btn-primary"
                                  (click)="setView(CalendarView.Month)"
                                  [class.active]="view === CalendarView.Month"
                                >
                                  Month
                                </div>
                                <div
                                  class="btn btn-primary"
                                  (click)="setView(CalendarView.Week)"
                                  [class.active]="view === CalendarView.Week"
                                >
                                  Week
                                </div>
                                <div
                                  class="btn btn-primary"
                                  (click)="setView(CalendarView.Day)"
                                  [class.active]="view === CalendarView.Day"
                                >
                                  Day
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <br />
                          <div [ngSwitch]="view">
                            <mwl-calendar-month-view
                              *ngSwitchCase="CalendarView.Month"
                              [viewDate]="viewDate"
                              [events]="events"
                              [refresh]="refresh"
                              [activeDayIsOpen]="activeDayIsOpen"
                              (dayClicked)="dayClicked($event.day)"
                              (eventClicked)="handleEvent('Clicked', $event.event)"
                              (eventTimesChanged)="eventTimesChanged($event)"
                            >
                            </mwl-calendar-month-view>
                            <mwl-calendar-week-view
                              *ngSwitchCase="CalendarView.Week"
                              [viewDate]="viewDate"
                              [events]="events"
                              [refresh]="refresh"
                              (eventClicked)="handleEvent('Clicked', $event.event)"
                              (eventTimesChanged)="eventTimesChanged($event)"
                            >
                            </mwl-calendar-week-view>
                            <mwl-calendar-day-view
                              *ngSwitchCase="CalendarView.Day"
                              [viewDate]="viewDate"
                              [events]="events"
                              [refresh]="refresh"
                              (eventClicked)="handleEvent('Clicked', $event.event)"
                              (eventTimesChanged)="eventTimesChanged($event)"
                            >
                            </mwl-calendar-day-view>
                          </div>
                          
                          <!-- Everything you see below is just for the demo, you don't need to include it in your app -->
                          
                          <br /><br /><br />
                          
                          <h3>
                            Edit events
                            <button class="btn btn-primary float-right" (click)="addEvent()">
                              Add new
                            </button>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                          </h3>
                          
                          <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-bordered">
                              <thead>
                                <tr>
                                  <th>Title</th>
                                  <th>Primary color</th>
                                  <th>Secondary color</th>
                                  <th>Starts at</th>
                                  <th>Ends at</th>
                                  <th>Remove</th>
                                </tr>
                              </thead>
                          
                              <tbody>
                                <tr *ngFor="let event of events">
                                  <td>
                                    <input
                                      type="text"
                                      class="form-control"
                                      [(ngModel)]="event.title"
                                      (keyup)="refresh.next()"
                                    />
                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                    <input
                                      type="color"
                                      [(ngModel)]="event.color.primary"
                                      (change)="refresh.next()"
                                    />
                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                    <input
                                      type="color"
                                      [(ngModel)]="event.color.secondary"
                                      (change)="refresh.next()"
                                    />
                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                    <input
                                      class="form-control"
                                      type="text"
                                      mwlFlatpickr
                                      [(ngModel)]="event.start"
                                      (ngModelChange)="refresh.next()"
                                      [altInput]="true"
                                      [convertModelValue]="true"
                                      [enableTime]="true"
                                      dateFormat="Y-m-dTH:i"
                                      altFormat="F j, Y H:i"
                                      placeholder="Not set"
                                    />
                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                    <input
                                      class="form-control"
                                      type="text"
                                      mwlFlatpickr
                                      [(ngModel)]="event.end"
                                      (ngModelChange)="refresh.next()"
                                      [altInput]="true"
                                      [convertModelValue]="true"
                                      [enableTime]="true"
                                      dateFormat="Y-m-dTH:i"
                                      altFormat="F j, Y H:i"
                                      placeholder="Not set"
                                    />
                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteEvent(event)">
                                      Delete
                                    </button>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </div>
                          
                          <ng-template #modalContent let-close="close">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                              <h5 class="modal-title">Event action occurred</h5>
                              <button type="button" class="close" (click)="close()">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                              </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                              <div>
                                Action:
                                <pre>{{ modalData?.action }}</pre>
                              </div>
                              <div>
                                Event:
                                <pre>{{ modalData?.event | json }}</pre>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="close()">
                                OK
                              </button>
                            </div>
                          </ng-template>
```

Here is my component.ts code

```
import {
  
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  ViewChild,
  TemplateRef,
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  startOfDay,
  endOfDay,
  subDays,
  addDays,
  endOfMonth,
  isSameDay,
  isSameMonth,
  addHours,
} from 'date-fns';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {
  CalendarEvent,
  CalendarEventAction,
  CalendarEventTimesChangedEvent,
  CalendarView,
} from 'angular-calendar';

const colors: any = {
  red: {
    primary: '#ad2121',
    secondary: '#FAE3E3',
  },
  blue: {
    primary: '#1e90ff',
    secondary: '#D1E8FF',
  },
  yellow: {
    primary: '#e3bc08',
    secondary: '#FDF1BA',
  },
};
// declare let $:any;
// declare var jQuery: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-attendance',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  templateUrl: './attendance.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./attendance.component.scss']
})



 
export class AttendanceComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('modalContent', { static: true })
  modalContent!: TemplateRef<any>;

  view: CalendarView = CalendarView.Month;

  CalendarView = CalendarView;

  viewDate: Date = new Date();

  modalData!: {
    action: string;
    event: CalendarEvent;
  };

  actions: CalendarEventAction[] = [
    {
      label: '<i class="fas fa-fw fa-pencil-alt"></i>',
      a11yLabel: 'Edit',
      onClick: ({ event }: { event: CalendarEvent }): void => {
        this.handleEvent('Edited', event);
      },
    },
    {
      label: '<i class="fas fa-fw fa-trash-alt"></i>',
      a11yLabel: 'Delete',
      onClick: ({ event }: { event: CalendarEvent }): void => {
        this.events = this.events.filter((iEvent) => iEvent !== event);
        this.handleEvent('Deleted', event);
      },
    },
  ];

  refresh = new Subject<void>();

  events: CalendarEvent[] = [
    {
      start: subDays(startOfDay(new Date()), 1),
      end: addDays(new Date(), 1),
      title: 'A 3 day event',
      color: colors.red,
      actions: this.actions,
      allDay: true,
      resizable: {
        beforeStart: true,
        afterEnd: true,
      },
      draggable: true,
    },
    {
      start: startOfDay(new Date()),
      title: 'An event with no end date',
      color: colors.yellow,
      actions: this.actions,
    },
    {
      start: subDays(endOfMonth(new Date()), 3),
      end: addDays(endOfMonth(new Date()), 3),
      title: 'A long event that spans 2 months',
      color: colors.blue,
      allDay: true,
    },
    {
      start: addHours(startOfDay(new Date()), 2),
      end: addHours(new Date(), 2),
      title: 'A draggable and resizable event',
      color: colors.yellow,
      actions: this.actions,
      resizable: {
        beforeStart: true,
        afterEnd: true,
      },
      draggable: true,
    },
  ];

  activeDayIsOpen: boolean = true;


  dayClicked({ date, events }: { date: Date; events: CalendarEvent[] }): void {
    if (isSameMonth(date, this.viewDate)) {
      if (
        (isSameDay(this.viewDate, date) && this.activeDayIsOpen === true) ||
        events.length === 0
      ) {
        this.activeDayIsOpen = false;
      } else {
        this.activeDayIsOpen = true;
      }
      this.viewDate = date;
    }
  }

  eventTimesChanged({
    event,
    newStart,
    newEnd,
  }: CalendarEventTimesChangedEvent): void {
    this.events = this.events.map((iEvent) => {
      if (iEvent === event) {
        return {
          ...event,
          start: newStart,
          end: newEnd,
        };
      }
      return iEvent;
    });
    this.handleEvent('Dropped or resized', event);
  }

  handleEvent(action: string, event: CalendarEvent): void {
    this.modalData = { event, action };
    this.modal.open(this.modalContent, { size: 'lg' });
  }

  addEvent(): void {
    this.events = [
      ...this.events,
      {
        title: 'New event',
        start: startOfDay(new Date()),
        end: endOfDay(new Date()),
        color: colors.red,
        draggable: true,
        resizable: {
          beforeStart: true,
          afterEnd: true,
        },
      },
    ];
  }

  deleteEvent(eventToDelete: CalendarEvent) {
    this.events = this.events.filter((event) => event !== eventToDelete);
  }

  setView(view: CalendarView) {
    this.view = view;
  }

  closeOpenMonthViewDay() {
    this.activeDayIsOpen = false;
  }
```

here is my module.ts file

```
import { CalendarModule, DateAdapter } from 'angular-calendar';
import { adapterFactory } from 'angular-calendar/date-adapters/date-fns';
import { NgbModalModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CalendarModule.forRoot({
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useFactory: adapterFactory,
    }),
FormsModule,
NgbModalModule
],
```

I'm getting error message like this.

```
error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
[(ngModel)]="event.color.primary"

Object is possibly 'undefined'.
[(ngModel)]="event.color.secondary"
                                                                  
 Can't bind to 'altInput' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.
[altInput]="true"

Can't bind to 'enableTime' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. [enableTime]="true"

Can't bind to 'convertModelValue' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.
[convertModelValue]="true"
```

can anyone help me out with these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors regarding `event.color.primary` should be the result, that your colors are of type `any` and there is no specific type defined.
Try to create a `IColors` interface and define the `primary` and `secondary` entries as string.

The errors regarding the `input` tag, result from not known attributes of the input HTML element to angular.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `color: colors.red` to `color: colors['red']`